# Why is the heatmap color not showing in TileMill?

Tags: qgis, tilemill

I created a heatmap on QGIS (2.8) and styled it using singleband pseudocolor.  I want to turn it into map tiles, so I added the TIFF as a layer in TileMill. However, when it's in TileMill, it loses the style settings from QGIS and becomes black and white. I'm not entirely sure if this is an issue with something I'm doing on QGIS or on TileMill.

I just started using QGIS a few days ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The styling inside QGIS is not part of the geotif.

It will not be written into the geotif (only in the .qgis project file), and hence tilemill does not know of it.

You can use the Qtiles plugin to create tiles directly from QGIS. You may need to enable for experimental plugins to see it in the plugin list.

You should set the **project** CRS to EPSG:3857 before starting  the plugin.